# How to add a Datasource to embedded Weblogic 12

Tags: datasource, weblogic12c

How can I add a datasource configuration file within a embedded Weblogic EJB Container?

As far as I know, this is only possible with a already installed and preconfigured weblogic, instance? Is this correct?

My configuration is the following:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("datasource.properties"));
EJBContainer container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(prop);

Context initialContext = container.getContext();

((MyEJB)initialContext.lookup("MyEjb")).writeInDatabase();
```

I have not found a lot of documentation on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

http://vineetreynolds.blogspot.com/2012/11/the-embedded-ejb-container-in-weblogic.html

see if this helps, although I cant get stuff to run yet on my end

you are better of being in jpa land, and create a test persistence.xml that basically uses jdbc url/user/pass and not jndi

Comment: I am wondering why this is so undocumented, because how you can configure existing queues. 
You also need to change your datasource configuration. This is like you use OpenEJB container and other 3rd libs to get this running.

embedded servertesting is a essential part of JEE6